# My account from brewadvice didn't merge with my homebrewing.stackoverflow account. Can I merge them?

Tags: support, status-completed, meta, brewadvice, user-accounts

My [old account](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/users/357/joe-lencioni) came over, but it didn't merge with my account that I created over here. Can I merge them? It would be nice to have my old questions and all of that under one account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accounts are now merged.